# Enviar valor de radiobutton de ajax a php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Anteriormente consulté sobre la forma de mandar el valor de un radio button a una variable en php  para que en el WHERE de la consulta se tomara dicho valor. Me recomendaron usar ajax, nunca lo había usado y estuve investigando un poco pero no logro que funcione y me arroja el siguiente error:
**Notice: Undefined index: peticion in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\Banco de Proyectos\index.php on line 141**.
Les explico un poco que se supone debe realizar.

Con este código traigo las carreras de la tabla carreras y en el value se obtiene el valor de el id de la carrera que es el que necesito recuperar posteriormente.

```
<form id= "b_p" role="form" action="" method="post" class="form-inline">
                            
<fieldset>
<!--<h4>Introducción <span class="step">(Paso 1 / 7)</span></h4>-->
<h2>Paso 1. Elige una carrera:</h2>
<p style="background-color:#891e35; color:white;"><b>[ De acuerdo al tipo de proyecto que requiere la empresa, elige la carrera de la cual requieras alumnos para su desarrollo. ]</b></p>
<br>
<section>
<div>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM carreras";
$resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
while( $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
?>
<div>
  <input type="radio"  id="carrera" name="carrera" value="<?php echo $record['id']; ?>">
  <label for="carrera">
    <h2><?php echo $record['abreviado']; ?></h2>
    <span>
        <img src="<?php echo $record['imagen']; ?>" width="40" height="40">
      </span>
    <p><?php echo $record['carrera']; ?></p>
  </label>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
</section>
                                    
<button type="button" id="btn_carrera"  class="btn btn-next">Siguiente <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>

</fieldset>
```

Con la selección del value de ese radiobutton en el siguiente fieldset me debería de cargar solo los proyectos que corresponden al id de esa carrera

```
<fieldset>
<h2>Paso 2. Elige un tipo de proyecto:</h2>
<p style="background-color:#891e35; color:white;"><b>[ De acuerdo a la necesidad que posee la empresa, elige el tipo de proyecto para el cual requieren alumnos para su desarrollo. ]</b></p>
<br>
<section>
<div>
<?php
$varAjax = $_POST['peticion'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM proyectos WHERE id_carrera = '$varAjax'";
$resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
while( $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
?>
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="proyectos" name="proyectos" value="<?php echo $record['id_tipo']; ?>">
  <label for="proyectos">
    <span>
        <img src="<?php echo $record['imagen']; ?>" width="40" height="40">
      </span>
    <p><?php echo $record['tipo']; ?></p>
  </label>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
                                    
</section>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-previous"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Anterior</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Siguiente <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
</fieldset>
```

Aquí mi código con ajax

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn_carrera");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var carr = document.getElementById("carrera").value;

    $.ajax({
        url:"./index.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{ peticion:carr },
    })//.done(function(res){
        //var result = JSON.parse(res);
        //console.log(result);
    });
```

Como extra aquí si puedo obtener el value

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
        {
        $("input[name=carrera]").change(function () {    
            alert($(this).val());
            });
 
         });
</script>
```

El script donde tengo el ajax se llama script.js y lo importo antes de cerrar el body. El error en si es el que mencioné al principio **Notice: Undefined index: peticion in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\Banco de Proyectos\index.php on line 141.**
Si alguien tiene alguna idea de como solucionarlo se lo agradecería.

**SOLUCIÓN**
Mi script con ajax quedó así:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('input[name="carrera"]').click(function(){  
           var carrera = $(this).val();  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"proceso.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{carrera:carrera}
             // imprimimos la respuesta
                //success:function(data){  
                     //$('#proyectos_proy').html(data);  
                     //alert (data);
               // }  

           }).done(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
        $('#proyectos_proy2').append(res);  
            });
        
      });  
 });
```

Separé mi código php del html que tenía en el index en el archivo llamado proceso.php donde puse la consulta e imprimí el html con `echo`
Así proceso.php

```
<?php
include("./conn.php");
$varAjax = $_POST['carrera'];
if(isset($_POST['carrera'])){ 
    $sql = "SELECT id, tipo, imagen FROM proyectos WHERE id_carrera = '$varAjax'";
$resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
while( $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {


echo '<section>
<div>
<div>
<input type="radio" id="proyectos" name="proyectos" value="'.$record['id'].'">

<label for="proyectos">
    <span>
        <img src="'.$record['imagen'].'" width="40" height="40">
      </span>
    <p>'.$record['tipo'].'</p>
  </label>
</div>

</div>
                                    
</section> ';


}
}
 ?>
```

Y en el index.php sólo dejé el div con `id="proyectos_proy2"`

```
<fieldset id="proyectos_proy">
<h2>Paso 2. Elige un tipo de proyecto:</h2>
<p style="background-color:#891e35; color:white;"><b>[ De acuerdo a la necesidad que posee la empresa, elige el tipo de proyecto para el cual requieren alumnos para su desarrollo. ]</b></p>
<br>
<div id="proyectos_proy2">
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-previous"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Anterior</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Siguiente <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Estan enviando a la misma pagina index?, ya verificaste las lineas donde te marca el error?, separa **php** de tu HTML, es mu mala practica, ademas de que dificulta encontrar el error. Estas usando Ajax, manda tus consultas a un script PHP indica la ruta y con echo recojes la data en Ajax.

Comment: La línea donde me marca el error es la 141, exactamente en esta parte del código `$varAjax = $_POST['peticion'];`

Comment: Por eso te pregunto, estas enviando dicho parámetro a la misma pagina?

Comment: Si, en script.js envío al index.php porque ahí tengo la consulta mysql, tengo el php con el html porque traigo los valores de la bd a los radio button

Comment: En principio en el done de AJAX ejecuta un alert con un mensaje, en caso de que la petición se ejecute correctamente y agrega **.fail** a tu Ajax, con esto verificamos si esta ejecutandose la petición correctamente o no, despues de eso agrega un ***if(isset($_POST['peticion'])){ echo 'Parametro recibido';}else{ echo 'No llego nada';}**. Con estos pasos vamos viendo donde esta el error, tambien verifica que la función del botón, encierrala dentro de esta funcion **window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {**, que estara disponible al terminar de cargarse el DOM, dime que sucede

Comment: Agregué `if(isset($_POST['peticion'])){ 
 echo 'Parámetro recibido';
}else{ 
 echo 'No llegó nada';}` y en efecto en la página me imprime el echo "no llegó nada", por otro lado en la función fail no me da nada pero en la consola me dice Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>, que es en la línea  `var carr = document.getElementById("carrera").value;`

Comment: Te comento, el enfoque de Ajax es enviar los parámetros a otra pagina, no en la misma porque no funcionara, ya comprobamos que no estamos recibiendo el valor mediante PHP, pasa tu consulta a otro fichero, con echo imprimes tu HTML, en el index agregas un **DIV** con una clase o id, y ahí pintamos la data de php.

Comment: `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
var btn = document.getElementById("btn_carrera");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
 var carr = document.getElementById("carrera").value;

 $.ajax({
  url:"index.php",
  method:"POST",
  data:{ peticion:carr },
 }).done(function(res) {
  alert(res); // imprimimos la respuesta
   }).fail(function() {
  alert("Algo salió mal");
   
 });
});

});` Así quedó el ajax

Comment: Haz lo que te comento, investiga un poco mas sobre AJAX, sepera tus scripts, no me da el tiempo para replicar tus script, ya mas o menos tienes idea de donde esta el problema, corrigelos y me dices cuales son los resultados, recuerda que puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/544668/edit) tu pregunta las veces que sean, no las agregues como comentarios.

Comment: Gracias @Antonio Galicia, hice lo que me indicaste y por fin pude resolverlo!, edité la pregunta con la solución.